# Debian Wheezy Places > Connect To Server Host Key Verification Failed

Tags: ssh, debian, connect

I've got a stumper.  First let me say that previously this worked fine, but since I made some changes to my sshd_config file (for added security) I am unable to connect to my Debian Wheezy box (from another Deb Wheezy box) using the

```
Places > Connect To Server options.
```

I will say that I can connect via ssh back and forth between boxes via a root terminal just fine, but I cannot connect using the same root login from one box to the other.  Anybody got any ideas on this?

The only log error I get on the host machine (`/var/log/auth.log`) is `Connection closed by XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [preauth]`.  Of course there are no log entries on the client machine.

Here's my `sshd_config` file from the HOST machine (Removed commented out lines for readability):

```
Port 22
Protocol
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
Banner /etc/ssh/ssh.banner
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM no
```

And here's the `ssh_config` file from my CLIENT machine (again, commented out lines removed)

```
Host *
PasswordAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

AFAIK, the only settings I changed prior to it working correctly were on the `sshd_config` file, probably just the `PasswordAuthentication RSAAuthentication` and/or `PubKeyAuthentication`.

Anybody got any ideas?  I've hunted around and couldn't find any solutions that worked.

Again, ssh via terminal works fine both ways, but not via `Places > Connect To Server` (settings SSH, port 22 with root user name and password.)  Connect To Server error message on screen shows Host Key Verification Failed.

Thanks in advance for enlightening me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit hnk.  I goofed on putting the config file info in.

Anybody got any ideas on this one?  BTW, I can successfully connect to two of the other three servers, just one of them fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. For the purposes of documentation, I thought I'd post the solution to this problem that I finally stumbled up. Probably a newbie mistake, but nonetheless here it is:

I actually discovered through trial and error that in fact when connecting through Places > Connect To Server, you are actually using the host key information stored in your /user/.ssh/known_hosts file, even if you are using the User Name : root and Password : XXXX in the Connect To Server box.

Therefore, clear out your known_hosts file in your /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts file and you should then be good to go.

In fact, I cleared the known_hosts file in all machines for both the root and USERNAME accounts just to be sure.

Problem solved!